# Is Logistic Regression Possible Using a Convenience Sample?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, sampling

I've collected some survey data on homeless individuals, surveying their drug use, education level, age, gender etc. I hope to run a logistic regression to see how impactful homelessness (+other dependent variables) are on the likelihood a child uses drugs.

DrugUser= B0 + B1Homeless + B3X3 + ... + u

However, due to the constraints of the study I was not able to survey randomly, only surveying those individuals who came into a homeless shelter (A convenience sample?). Hence the majority of the sample were made up of homeless people. Does this mean that any results I get for B1 would be spurious, as almost all of the sample is of homeless children and not a randomised sample of the population?

Therefore, is there anyway I can measure the effect of homelessness on drug use considering the quality of the data?

If not, could I still accurately measure the effects of the other variables on the likelihood an individual takes drugs that are not made bias by this convenience sample (like age, gender etc.)?

Is there any way I can use survey data like this to run a logistic regression at all?

Comment: You can run a logistic regression on whatever data you want. Whether the results from that model can be interpreted as generalizing to your population of interest and as causal estimates rather than just associations is another story.

Comment: @Noah concisely makes very important points that are worthy of a great deal of study.  In addition, think about what it means for the "variable" of homelessness if it does not vary.

Comment: @Noah Thank you both for commenting. Yeah I can appreciate correlation does not infer causation. What then are the other things one could do to supplement a correlation? For example I have done more in depth interviews and collected qualitative data to the effect of homelessness contributing to drug use, would this information supplementing a positive correlation be strong enough evidence to infer causation?

Comment: Also, @rolando2 I did not properly explain that the data pool is not entirely taken from homeless individuals, it includes some non-homeless respondents, but my worry is not enough for it to be considered random pooling and hence regression would produce an unbias parameter estimate. Thanks again

Comment: Establishing causality is a huge challenge in general. I recommend you seek professional statistical consulting or collaborate with a statistician if this is a serious project.

Comment: You could purposely ("purposively") sample some non-homeless people as a comparison group.  Your method of obtaining that sample, and the extent to which they represent *some* specified population, will determine the extent to which your analytic results can validly be generalized to that population and the homeless one.  You needn't necessarily account for society as a whole.